# MySQL ,using ORDER BY with 2 key

Tags: mysql

Hi I have MySQL table look like this...

```
+----+------+----------+------+
| id | name | priority | room |
+----+------+----------+------+
| 1  |  AA  |    2     | 507  |
| 2  |  BB  |    3     | 507  |
| 3  |  CC  |    1     | 405  |
| 4  |  DD  |    4     | 405  |
| 5  |  EE  |    6     | 205  |
| 6  |  FF  |    8     | 405  |
| 7  |  GG  |    7     | 205  |
| 8  |  HH  |    5     | 405  |
+----+------+----------+------+
```

and I want result of query look like this..

```
+----+------+----------+------+
| id | name | priority | room |
+----+------+----------+------+
| 3  |  CC  |    1     | 405  |
| 4  |  DD  |    4     | 405  |
| 8  |  HH  |    5     | 405  |
| 6  |  FF  |    8     | 405  |
| 1  |  AA  |    2     | 507  |
| 2  |  BB  |    3     | 507  |
| 5  |  EE  |    6     | 205  |
| 7  |  GG  |    7     | 205  |
+----+------+----------+------+
```

I want to order room's field and priority's field

I try to using "ORDER BY priority, room" and "ORDER BY room, priority" but not work..

Can anyone help? please...Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `order by room desc, priority`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT id, name, priority, room 
FROM table
ORDER BY room DESC, priority
```

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html):

> The default sort order is ascending, with smallest values first. To sort in reverse (descending) order, add the DESC keyword to the name of the column you are sorting by

So you need to add `DESC` to the `room` column but you don't need a modifier for the `priority` column.

Answer (score 0):

The below query would give a result based on the result which you have requested.

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`priority`,`room`
FROM table_name
ORDER BY `room` DESC;
```